# Android: Sending / Receiving data between two systems

Tags: android

I used TCPsocket for communicating client and server.

**Client code:**

```
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 21111;
Socket s = new Socket(inet, TCP_SERVER_PORT);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
String outMsg = "connect" + TCP_SERVER_PORT+System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
out.write(outMsg);
out.flush();
Log.i("TcpClient", "Client sent - : " + outMsg);
String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
textReceived.append("Client received - : " + inMsg);
Log.i("TcpClient", "Client received  - : " + inMsg);
s.close();
```

**Server code:**

```
ServerSocket ss = null;
int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 21111;
ss = new ServerSocket(TCP_SERVER_PORT);
Socket s = ss.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
Log.i("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
textDisplay.append("Server received - : " + incomingMsg);
String outgoingMsg = "Port " + TCP_SERVER_PORT + System.getProperty("line.separator");
out.write(outgoingMsg);
out.flush();
Log.i("TcpServer", "sent: " + outgoingMsg);
textDisplay.append("Server sent - : " + outgoingMsg);
s.close();
```

I used single emulator to test this program in my system. Its working fine. 
Now i need to communicate with two computers.

Comment: when you say two computers, do you mean you need to test this running between two instances of the emulator?

Comment: Two emulators with different computers

Answer (score 0):

As each emulator instance sits behind a virtual firewall, you will need to allow ports on your host machine to redirect to your emulator instance.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) page has details of how to connect to the emulator instance via telnet and enable port redirects.

If you run an emulator on each machine and then setup port redirects, you should be able to reach one emulator instance from the other by specifying the host machine's IP and port. As you have a redirect in place, your host machine should pick it up and redirect it to the emulator instance.